# Can we recognize different events in time-series data by patterns?

Tags: time-series, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification

I'm currently have to deal with multiple time-series datasets with the same type of patterns. My quest is to find a way to label these data points (or may be intervals) correctly. Below is how the datasets looked like:

```
Time             Value
2012-04-30T08:52 1.06
2012-04-30T08:53 0.82
2012-04-30T08:54 0.65
2012-04-30T08:55 1.12
2012-04-30T08:56 1.09
2012-04-30T08:57 0.65
```

*This is just for reference

[image][image]

**Target is to be able to segment the input time-series from measurement in linear patches that are consistent (i.e that are not showing any activities on the scale).**

Then from that segmented time-series, it will be needed to measure the start / end time (and thus duration) of each segment and to classify those segments into “activities” such as:

-No tray (Constant)

-Idle (Constant)

-Taking item (Value decrease)

-Putting item (Value increase)

-Working (Constant)

So, I have 2 approaches to this problem, but I am not confident since this is my first time encounter a problem like this.

- My 1st approach is to manually label the dataset and find a suitable algorithm for this problem. However, I believe that it will not yield good results when the measurements are radically different.
- My second approach is to mechanically set multiple ranges and thresholds to determine the result. But, the same problems with my 1st approach still seems to be there.
  All in all, I think this problem is not new, and there should be someone encountered this kind of problem already. So, I'm posting here hoping for some good advice.

Comment: Have you thought of using a sliding window to analyze whether the signal is constant, decreasing or increasing? This won't solve your problem of which activity the segment belongs to, but it could be a way of measuring when you move from one activity to another because there would be a change in the moving average over the window size.